# Como retornar índices de array em método

Tags: php, array, loop, foreach

Bom não consegui achar um título melhor para o meu caso, tenho a seguinte **função**:

```
public function select_tokens() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

    $select_tokens = Database::DB()->prepare($sql);
    $select_tokens->execute();
    $fetch = $select_tokens->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($fetch as $token) {
        $tokens[] = [
            'user_token' => $token['user_token'],
            'user_token2' => $token['user_token2']
        ];
    }
    return $tokens;
}
```

Repare, estou retornando `$tokens` que no caso eu poderia usar assim:

```
$tk = $users->select_tokens();
```

E depois pegar o índice:

```
$tk['user_token'];
```

ou

```
$tk['user_token2'];
```

Mas não sei o porque me retorna este erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: user_token

ou

> Notice: Undefined index: user_token2

**Obs:** Quero pegar **todos** `tokens` de **todos** usuários da tabela `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está criando um array composto de outros arrays aqui:

```
$tokens[] = [
    'user_token' => $token['user_token'],
    'user_token2' => $token['user_token2']
];
```

Portanto para acessar os arrays internos você iterar sobre o array principal, ou referenciar a chave que você quer, por exemplo:

```
// 0 é a chave do primeiro array criado no foreach ali em cima.
// e eles são numerados em sequência, 0, 1, 2, 3 etc
$tk[0]['user_token'];
```

Se quiser usar `user_token` como a chave principal, pode criar um array para cada tipo de token:

```
foreach ($fetch as $token) {
    $tokens['user_token'][] = $token['user_token'];
    $tokens['user_token2'][] => $token['user_token2'];
    ];
}
```

Agora você pode fazer assim:

```
var_dump( $tokens['user_token'] );
// Array( [0] => token0, [1] => token1, [2] => token2, etc );
```

Comment: Sim, porém ele me retorna apenas `1` token no caso do primeiro ID, eu quero pegar os 10 que contém na tabela. Eu tentei desta forma.

Comment: Editei a resposta pra mostrar como pegar todos em uma chave só

Comment: Show, é o que eu queria, funcionou. Valeu.